# s.bind((hostMACAddress,port)). OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: python-3.x, windows, sockets, bluetooth, mac-address

I am trying to use the Bluetooth library in python 3 to enable me to allow a robot I am making to communicate with my PC. I have created a Bluetooth server that uses MAC addresses. unfortunately I have hit a halt in my program on this line:

```
s.bind((hostMACAddress,port))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

For some reason it does not seem to like the MAC address (I have checked over the MAC address several times now and it is definitely correct). Personally, I would rather not want to use python 2 as the robot I am using is only compatible with python 3 and by using python 2 the whole idea would not work.

```
"""
A simple Python script to receive messages from a client over
Bluetooth using Python sockets (with Python 3.3 or above).
"""

import socket

hostMACAddress = 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx' # The MAC address of a Bluetooth adapter on the server. The server might have multiple Bluetooth adapters.
port = 3 # 3 is an arbitrary choice. However, it must match the port used by the client.
backlog = 1
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.bind((hostMACAddress,port))
s.listen(backlog)
try:
    client, address = s.accept()
    while 1:
        data = client.recv(size)
        if data:
            print(data)
            client.send(data)
except: 
    print("Closing socket") 
    client.close()
    s.close()
```

Here is the guide I have been following:
https://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/

These lines I have used alternatively to using MAC addresses (I am have tried using both):

```
hostIPAddress = "x.x.x.x"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((hostIPAddress,22))
```

Comment: Does the MAC address in question belong to the device that your Python server script is running on? Or is it the MAC address of the other device that is trying to connect to the server?  Is it not really clear from your description which device connects to which device.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It is the MAC address of the robot I am trying to send the data to.

Comment: You did not answer any of my questions. Which device is `listen()`'ing and which device is `connect()`'ing? Is the PC `listen()`'ing and the robot is `connect()`'ing to the PC, or the other way around? Which device is running the script shown - the PC, or the robot?  You can't `bind()` to something that exists outside of the device the script is running on. So, for instance, if this script is running on the PC, then it can't `bind()` to the robot's MAC, only to one of its own local MACs. The script can `bind()` to the robot's MAC only if the script is running on the robot.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The robot is listening for a connection from my PC. This script above is running on my PC.

Comment: "*This script above is running on my PC*" - then the PC is using the wrong script, which is why the `bind()` is failing. The script above is based on Kevin Doran's server script, not the client script. The PC is trying to act as a server that `listen()`'s for a connection from the robot. But if the robot is the one `listen()`'ing, then the robot needs to act as a server that `bind()`'s to the robot's MAC and `listen()`'s for connections, and the PC needs to act as a client that `connect()`'s to the robot's MAC.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I switched the programs around but the robot got an error saying: no module named AF.BLUETOOTH. So I switched to using IP addresses instead of MAC addresses, for the client this worked fine but for the server (the robot) I got an error which I was not familiar with: ```OSError: 99``` In addition, I am also not too sure which ports are open on the robot, I definitely know port 22 for SSH is open.